# postgres: filter out some results with join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I’m trying to construct SQL query (I’m running postgres) which would filter out some posts:

Lets say, that I’ve fot User model(id, name, and so on...), Blacklist model(with id, user_id, blacklisted_user_id) nad Post model(id, author_id, title, and so on).

Imagine that user A(id=5) blocks user B(id=10).

Neither user A nor B should see their posts.
I’m trying with query which looks sth. like this:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM "posts" 
LEFT JOIN blacklists b ON (b.user_id = posts.author_id OR 
                           b.blacklisted_user_id = posts.author_id)
WHERE (b.user_id = 5 AND b.blacklisted_user_id = posts.author_id) OR
      (b.user_id = posts.author_id AND b.blacklisted_user_id = 5)
```

However, result is exactly opposite that I need: I’m getting only posts from blacklisted user.

When I use `b.user_id != 5`, I’m getting empty response.

Comment: You have a condition to the "outer joined table" (blacklists) in the `WHERE` clause which effectively turns the whole thing into an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

You're repeating the blacklisted_user_id=posts.author_id which is unnecessary.

Then, you presumably want posts that don't match the blacklist. Something like:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN blacklists b ON (b.user_id = posts.author_id OR 
                           b.blacklisted_user_id = posts.author_id)
WHERE posts.author_id = 5 AND b.user_id IS NULL
```

Is that the sort of thing you wanted?

Comment: Nope, I’m not repeating. See, that I’d like to use ```blacklisted_user_id``` OR ```user_id``` (so blacklisting is symmetrical)

Comment: Yes, and then you *repeat* the conditions in the WHERE clause. Which is where your problem is. If I've understood correctly you want NON-blacklisted posts.